# Deadlock in producer-consumer using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, consumer, producer

I'm using pthreads to solve a producer-consumer problem. Basicaly the producer reads a file to a buffer and the consumers (at least one, but not limited) take entries from the buffer and operate them one by one.
This is the producer:

```
//...Local stuff...
if(file){
    while(fgets(line, 256, file)){            
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);            
        while(data->buffer->buffer_items == data->buffer->buffer_size){               
            pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_full_cv, &buffer_mutex);}
        data->buffer->buffer_items);
        reads++;
        add_to_head(data->buffer, line);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_ready_cv);            
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);            
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    work = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    fclose(file);
}
```

And this is the consumer:

```
//...Local stuff...
while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);        
    while(data->buffer->buffer_items == 0){
        if(work)
            pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_ready_cv, &buffer_mutex);            
        else if(!work && !data->buffer->buffer_items)
            pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    remove_from_tail(data->buffer, string_to_check);
    data->buffer->buffer_items);
    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_full_cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->num_substrings; i++){    
        cur_occurrence = strstr(string_to_check, data->substrings[i]);
        while(cur_occurrence != NULL){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
            data->occurrences[i]++;
            cur_occurrence++;
            cur_occurrence = strstr(cur_occurrence, data->substrings[i]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
        }
    }
}
```

What seems to be happening is the file is completely read and there's still work to be done, but as the producer is not running anymore, the wait in the consumer never finishes.

> PS.: I've also tried pthread_cond_signal instead of broadcast, but didn't work either.

Anyway, Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: 'the wait in the consumer never finishes' yes.  Is that some sort of problem?

Comment: I mean, can you not just leave them?  Do you HAVE to terminate them explicitly?

Comment: If i just leave them, when will they end? Edit: The main must return a value that will only be ready after all consumers are finished. If they never end when will it return?

Answer (score 1):

> What seems to be happening is the file is completely read and there's still work to be done, but as the producer is not running anymore, the wait in the consumer never finishes.

Technically, this is not a deadlock.  This is a common challenge with producer/consumer thread configurations.  There are various ways to deal with this.

- You could use a special buffer value (separate from the empty buffer) which signals that the producer has finished.  (If you have multiple consumers, this special value has to be left in the buffer.)  Such in-band signaling, while sometimes convenient to implement, is typically not a good design, though.
- If you have multiple producers, you probably should combine the buffer with a counter of the number of producers running, essentially adding a semaphore to the buffer.  If the count of producers reaches zero, the consumers need to exit.
- The thread which spawns the producers and consumers could use `pthread_cancel` after joining all consumers, so that `pthread_cond_wait` is aborted.  This is tricky to get completely right, though, and cancellation is best avoided in general.

Note that if you have multiple consumers, each one needs to broadcast the signal after it observed that the end-of-data state has been reached, so that the other consumers have a chance to observe it, too,

Comment: O tried using the "work" flag but with more than 2 consumers the same problem happened. Eventually the buffer gets empty but there's nothing more to be loaded, so the producer thread ends, but there's still data inside the buffer. When the buffer is finally empty, the threads that are still running get stucked waiting for a signal that never comes. At least this is the conclusion i got after debugging the code. Also there's only one producer and canceling the threads may not be a good Idea because one of them could still be processing some data - unless It cancels only threads that are waiting

Comment: See the last paragraph. The consumers need to broadcast a signal at the end, they exit.

Comment: But the consumers don't know If the buffer is empty because the producer stopped reading the file or if it's still reading. I thought about that but i couldn't figure a way to make this signalings.

Comment: That's why I wrote *a special buffer buffer value*. The empty buffer is not such a value. Sorry for being unclear. You can always use a separate flag or the counter of running producers. In-band signaling is usually not a good idea.

Comment: But wouldn't this value be the same as "work" in MT code? Just to be clear, work is an int initialized as 1. Once the fgets loop ends, It is set to 0. Still, It appears that the time between the end of the loop and the execution of the attribution os enough to allow the consumers to enter waiting state. I've also tried broadcast after the file is read by the producer, bit It wasn't enough to release all threads.

Comment: Did you broadcast from all the consumers after they observed the `!work` state?

Comment: I've tried "pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_ready_cv)" right before the thread exists, but no success.

Comment: 'In-band signaling is usually not a good idea' why would that be?  It's common practice.

Comment: For instance, on the very few occasions I've had to shut down a pool like this, I've used NULL as the 'poison pill'.  Every consumer that gets NULL pushes the NULL back onto the queue and terminates. NULL does not need to be freed/deleted, so there's no issue with the last pool thread to die needing to deal with it.